# Where to unregister BroadcastReceiver (in a service)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver that I create dynamically in a Service.  Its purpose is to detect when an SMS has been sent.  It works as expected.

My trouble is that I receive an error saying "the Intent Receiver has leaked".  Am I missing a call to `unregisterReceiver()`?

I am making the call to `unregisterReceiver()` in `onDestroy()`.  I guess this must be wrong.  Where should I unregister the receiver?

***Code...***

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver brSms;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        //Define the receiver
        brSms = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Do some  stuff
            };
        }

        registerReceiver(brSms, new IntentFilter(SENT_SMS_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(brSms);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy has been called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}//end of MyService
```

Comment: Your code looks right: are you throwing any exceptions shortly before you see the leak notification?

Comment: Service.onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 11):

Try like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    BroadcastReceiver brSms;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        brSms = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Do some  stuff
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(brSms, new IntentFilter(SENT_SMS_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(brSms);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy has been called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what's causing your error message, but to answer your question, you're doing it absolutely correctly to unregister in `onDestroy()`. I know from experience that this works well, and it's also a good place to do it according to the [documentation for Service.onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy%28%29):

> ... The service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, *registered receivers*, etc) at this point. ...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `onStart()`... try `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call super.onDestroy().

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(brSms);
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy has been called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope this will work for you.